# 150% Scaling adds large padding to windows applications

Tags: windows, resolution, windows-10-v1809

I'm having trouble getting the scaling to work properly with Windows 10 on a 3840x2160 display.

Windows10 Pro version: 1809 (OS Build 17763.504)

All Windows 10 apps, such as Settings, Sticky Notes, Calc etc are given large areas of padding when set to 150% scale. All other non-windows apps, such as google chrome are fine.

I can't read text on the display unless the scaling is set to at least 150%

Please see images for example.

Thanks

No scaling.(The image makes it look ok but I can't read the text like this):
[image]

150%:
[image]

More examples:
[image]

Comment: I was unable to reproduce on my 4k Windows 10 1809 setup.  What version of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: windows 10 pro 64bit - fully upto date

Comment: That isn’t the information I am looking for. Use **winver** to provide the information to clarify which version of Windows 10 you are using.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment